# Filter a top level JSONB array document in Postgres?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a Postgres table named 'events' with a column  of 'id', 'name', 'invoices':

```
                                           Table "public.events"
        Column         |            Type             |                           Modifiers
-----------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 id                    | integer                     | not null default nextval('events_id_seq'::regclass)
 name                  | character varying(255)      | not null
 invoices              | jsonb                       | not null
```

Each row has a invoices column of type jsonb with an array as a top level element:

```
Example Content:

[{"InvoiceId":4,"CustomerId":14,"InvoiceDate":"2009-01-06T00:00:00","BillingAddress":"8210 111 ST NW","BillingCity":"Edmonton","BillingState":"AB","BillingCountry":"Canada","BillingPostalCode":"T6G 2C7","Total":8.91}, 
 {"InvoiceId":5,"CustomerId":23,"InvoiceDate":"2009-01-11T00:00:00","BillingAddress":"69 Salem Street","BillingCity":"Boston","BillingState":"MA","BillingCountry":"USA","BillingPostalCode":"2113","Total":13.86}, 
 {"InvoiceId":8,"CustomerId":40,"InvoiceDate":"2009-02-01T00:00:00","BillingAddress":"8, Rue Hanovre","BillingCity":"Paris","BillingState":null,"BillingCountry":"France","BillingPostalCode":"75002","Total":1.98}, 
 {"InvoiceId":9,"CustomerId":42,"InvoiceDate":"2009-02-02T00:00:00","BillingAddress":"9, Place Louis Barthou","BillingCity":"Bordeaux","BillingState":null,"BillingCountry":"France","BillingPostalCode":"33000","Total":3.96}, 
 {"InvoiceId":10,"CustomerId":46,"InvoiceDate":"2009-02-03T00:00:00","BillingAddress":"3 Chatham Street","BillingCity":"Dublin","BillingState":"Dublin","BillingCountry":"Ireland","BillingPostalCode":null,"Total":5.94}, 
 {"InvoiceId":11,"CustomerId":52,"InvoiceDate":"2009-02-06T00:00:00","BillingAddress":"202 Hoxton Street","BillingCity":"London","BillingState":null,"BillingCountry":"United Kingdom","BillingPostalCode":"N1 5LH","Total":8.91}, 
 {"InvoiceId":13,"CustomerId":16,"InvoiceDate":"2009-02-19T00:00:00","BillingAddress":"1600 Amphitheatre Parkway","BillingCity":"Mountain View","BillingState":"CA","BillingCountry":"USA","BillingPostalCode":"94043-1351","Total":0.99}, 
 {"InvoiceId":14,"CustomerId":17,"InvoiceDate":"2009-03-04T00:00:00","BillingAddress":"1 Microsoft Way","BillingCity":"Redmond","BillingState":"WA","BillingCountry":"USA","BillingPostalCode":"98052-8300","Total":1.98}, 
 {"InvoiceId":15,"CustomerId":19,"InvoiceDate":"2009-03-04T00:00:00","BillingAddress":"1 Infinite Loop","BillingCity":"Cupertino","BillingState":"CA","BillingCountry":"USA","BillingPostalCode":"95014","Total":1.98}, 
 {"InvoiceId":16,"CustomerId":21,"InvoiceDate":"2009-03-05T00:00:00","BillingAddress":"801 W 4th Street","BillingCity":"Reno","BillingState":"NV","BillingCountry":"USA","BillingPostalCode":"89503","Total":3.96}]
```

How do i return a request set with a list of each rows id, name, and array of invoices that have a "Total" Greater than 5.00?

Comment: You mean all events with any invoice bigger than 5? Or all events which sum of invoices is bigger than 5? And filter only those invoices bigger than 5 or return all invoices regardless of the total?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id, name, invoices
from
    events
    cross join lateral
    jsonb_array_elements(invoices) o (o)
group by 1,2,3
having sum((o ->> 'Total')::numeric > 5)
```